# What is the best way to dynamic cell content?

Tags: swift, dynamic, uicollectionviewcell

I'm working with collectionView to create a feed app and have done most things, but I have some question to improve my code:
For example, I have a status cell like this:

[image]

Usually, to dynamic cell content, I'll resize the cell in the delegate sizeForItemAt like this:

```
func collectionView(_ collectionView: UICollectionView, layout collectionViewLayout: UICollectionViewLayout, sizeForItemAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> CGSize {

    print(")-Layouting each cell")

    let textView = UITextView()
    textView.isScrollEnabled = false
    textView.font = UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
    textView.text = posts[indexPath.item].statusText

    let estimatedSizeForStatus = textView.sizeThatFits(CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: .infinity))


    return CGSize(width: view.frame.width, height: 470 + estimatedSizeForStatus.height)
}
```

But it's hard for me to maintain the code. When I want to change the status font size, I'll have to replace the code in 2 places (in the delegate and cell class).

Is there a better way to improve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use Table View or Collection View with Auto-resizing Custom Cells and Auto-Layout:

https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells

https://engineering.shopspring.com/dynamic-cell-sizing-in-uicollectionview-fd95f614ef80

For displaying the text - you could use a UILabel instead of UITextView. Set the .numberOfLines to 0, which will allow it to resize to as much as needed. And do not forget to add the proper Leading, Trailing, Top and Bottom constraints for it as well.

More advanced:

- You can create a custom .plist, .xml, .json etc. file containing all the UI info / Theme Settings where you'll keep the font names and sizes for each label, button and so on
- Load that info and make it available to the View Controller
- Check if a custom font was specified in that file. If Yes - use it, and the code will use it everywhere. If No - just use some default text as you did above.
- You'll have to use the ternary operator or the  coalescing operator everywhere you may need to use "Dynamic View Styling" values.

Your code will become something like this:

```
textView.font = ThemeSettings.headerTextFont() != nil ? ThemeSettings.headerTextFont() : UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
```

or:

```
textView.font = ThemeSettings.headerTextFont() ?? UIFont.preferredFont(forTextStyle: .subheadline)
```

And, you'll have to do the same in any other place that uses similar code that depends on the specific UI element's font.

The advantage is that you'll never have to mess with the code anymore, and only will do it once in the ThemeSettings file instead.

Comment: Very appreciate, @ppalancica. But I expect to have a more efficient way. What I mean is a way that I don't really need to estimate the size of text in the delegate.

Comment: If you use table views with auto-resizing rows, you don't have to write heightForRow(at:) method. The system will calculate it for you. See an example here: https://www.raywenderlich.com/8549-self-sizing-table-view-cells

Comment: I love coding programmatically (not use storyboard) and usually I use collection views for a list of data due to its customization. But I'll consider your point, thanks @ppalancica

Comment: Just found an article that explains how to do it for Collection View Cells too: https://engineering.shopspring.com/dynamic-cell-sizing-in-uicollectionview-fd95f614ef80

Note that whether programmatically or in storyboard, the cell has to be able to figure out its height and width based on the constraints you'll make.